# Run bash shell in parallel and wait

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parallel-processing

I have 100 files in a directory, and want to process each one with several steps, while step1 is time-consuming. So the pseudocode is like:

```
for filename in ~/dir/*; do
  run_step1 filename >${filename}.out &
done

for outfile in ~/dir/*.out; do
  run_step2 outfile >${outfile}.result
done
```

My question is how can I check if step1 is complete for a given input file. I used to use threads.join in C#, but not sure if bash shell has equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare -a PROCNUMS
ITERATOR=0
for filename in ~/dir/*; do
    run_step1 filename >${filename}.out &
    PROCNUMS[$ITERATOR]=$!
    let "ITERATOR=ITERATOR+1"
done

ITERATOR=0
for outfile in ~/dir/*.out; do
    wait ${PROCNUMS[$ITERATOR]}
    run_step2 outfile >${outfile}.result
    let "ITERATOR=ITERATOR+1"
done
```

This will make an array of the created processes then wait for them in order as they need to be completed, not it relies on the fact there is a 1 to 1 relationship between in and out files and the directory is not changed while it is running.

Not for a small performance boost you can now run the second loop asynchronously too if you like assuming each file is independant.

I hope this helps, but if you have any questions please comment.

Comment: You could tighten this up by putting the filenames in an array and using the array index expansion `${!filenames[@]}` to both iterate over the filenames and as the iterator.

Comment: @kojiro Sorry, but what you describe goes beyond my bash foo. I normally use fish, any chance you could expand slightly on this? How would I then get the PIDs out for use in the second loop?

Comment: Here are two solutions using the same logic as your answer, but making better use of bash features: https://gist.github.com/kojiromike/10995204

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want:

```
for filename in ~/dir/*
do
    (
    run_step1 $filename >${filename}.out
    run_step2 ${filename}.out >${filename}.result
    ) &
done
wait
```

This processes each file in a separate sub-shell, running first step 1 then step 2 on each file, but processing multiple files in parallel.

About the only issue you'll need to worry about is ensuring you don't try running too many processes in parallel.  You might want to consider GNU `parallel`.

You might want to write a trivial script (`doit.sh`, perhaps):

```
run_step1 "$1" > "$1.out"
run_step2 "$1.out" > "$1.result"
```

and then invoke that script from `parallel`, one file per invocation.

Comment: This isn't quite the same though. The question's pseudocode and @Vality's answer would run `run_step1` in parallel, but `run_step2` could only happen in serial, even for distinct files. With this answer, `run_step2` could be running more than once.

Comment: @kojiro: you're correct that it isn't identical.  It depends on whether the processing of the files is independent or not.  If, as it appears, each file can be processed independently, this gives the required result.  If the processing of files is not independent, then of course this cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

[The Bash builtin `wait`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html) can wait for a specific background job or all background jobs to complete. The simple approach would be to just insert a `wait` in between your two loops. If you'd like to be more specific, you could save the PID for each background job and `wait PID` directly before `run_step2` inside the second loop.

Comment: Capture the pid with `$!` and pass that to `wait`.

Answer (score 0):

After the loop that executes step1 you could write another loop that executes `fg` command which moves last process moved to background  into foreground.

You should be aware that `fg` could return an error if a process already finished.

After the loop with `fg`s you are sure that all steps1 have finished.